# plpgSQL return record type from FUNCTION

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use a plgSQL witch return me a record type :

```
CREATE FUNCTION actu(id INTEGER) RETURNS RECORD  AS $$
    DECLARE 
      ret RECORD;
    BEGIN
      SELECT id_photo, id_user, lien, titre 
            FROM photo 
            WHERE id_user IN (
                                SELECT id_userabo 
                                FROM abo 
                                WHERE id_user = id ) 
            ORDER BY date_publi DESC LIMIT 10;

    RETURN ret;
    END;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I'm trying to use it with :

```
SELECT * FROM actu(4)
AS (id_photo Integer, id_photo Integer, lien Varchar, titre Varchar);
```

pgAdmin4 send me error :

ERROR: ERROR: the request has no destination for the resulting data
HINT: If you want to cancel the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT: PL/pgsql function fil_actu(integer), line 5 with SQL statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate error is, that the result of a `select` statement needs to be stored somewhere (that's what the error says). You would need to use `select .. into ret from ...` to store the result, but that wouldn't work as a variable of type `record` can only store one row from a result.

You apparently want to return more than just one row, so you need to define the function as `returns table()` and then use [`return query`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4) in PL/pgSQL to return the result of a query. But for a simple function encapsulating a SELECT query, a `language sql` function is more efficient.

```
CREATE FUNCTION actu(id INTEGER) 
  -- adjust the data types for the returned columns!
  RETURNS table (id_photo int, id_user int, lien text, titre text)
AS $$
  SELECT id_photo, id_user, lien, titre 
  FROM photo 
  WHERE id_user IN (SELECT id_userabo 
                    FROM abo 
                    WHERE id_user = id ) 
  ORDER BY date_publi DESC 
  LIMIT 10;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

You can use that function like this:

```
select *
from actu(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may define those types inside the function, but with different names for the types. The return type can be a `TABLE` type and use `RETURN QUERY` to return the results.

```
CREATE FUNCTION actu(id INTEGER) RETURNS TABLE 
(typ_id_photo Integer, typ_id_user Integer, typ_lien Varchar, typ_titre Varchar) 
AS $$
    BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY   
     SELECT id_photo, id_user, lien, titre 
  FROM photo p 
  WHERE id_user IN (SELECT id_userabo 
                    FROM abo 
                    WHERE id_user = id ) 
  ORDER BY date_publi DESC 
  LIMIT 10;

    END;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```